# mySQL query between two dates and two times

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to query a mySQL table to pull out data between two dates and two times. I know how to do this for a single "datetime" column using the "between" call but my columns are one "date" column, and one "time" column. All the solution I can find online are for single datetime columns.

My ranges go from "day1" at 15:30 to day1+1day at 15:14

So far I can get the following range (which works):

```
SELECT time,
       close 
  FROM intraday_values 
 WHERE date="2005-03-01" 
   and time between "15:30" and "23:59"
```

But I obviously need to incorporate 2 dates and two times. I have tried the following but get an error:

```
SELECT time,
       close 
  FROM intraday_values 
       between date="2005-03-01" 
   and time="15:30" 
   and date="2005-03-02" 
   and time = "15:14"
```

Could someone help me formulate the query correctly? Many thanks

Comment: Can't you combine date and time and create time and compare those time values on the fly?

Comment: You got an error because you missed a chunk out the query (the `where` clause). This is why well formatted code is a must.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if your date field is indexed.  If they are then the "concat" examples others have given may not perform very well.

As an alternative you can use a query of the form:

```
select * 
  from foo 
 where (date > lower_date and date < upper_date) -- technically this clause isn't needed if they are a day apart
    or (date = lower_date and time >= lower_time)
    or (date = upper_date and time <= upper_time)
```

It's not pretty but it works and will allow mysql to make use of indexes on the date field if they exist.

So your query would be

```
SELECT time,
       close 
  FROM intraday_values 
 where (date > "2005-03-01" and date < "2005-03-02")
    or (date = "2005-03-01" and time >= "15:30")
    or (date = "2005-03-02" and time <= "15:14")
```

Comment: H, this worked with a slight adjustment. I removed the "where (date > "2005-03-01" and date = "2005-03-02")" as that was bringing back data until midnight on the second date. So without that part, it got be exactly what i wanted - many thanks!

Comment: Woops. I've just corrected it.  but yes you're right, that first clause isn't needed. only if you need to bring in more days at once.

Answer (score 0):

Use `concat` to combine these two column and `cast` it to `datetime` for the best results

```
SELECT 
time,close 
FROM 
intraday_values 
where  
cast(concat(date," ",time)  as datetime) 
between 
cast("2005-03-01 15:30") as datetime 
and cast("2005-03-02 15:14") as datetime
```

Comment: Thanks guys, but strangely both of these suggestions bring down the data for the second date in the string between 00:01 and 23:59 which doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: may be your input is varchar ,try to cast