# SQL: Selecting the time range between two column

Tags: mysql, sql-server

i am working on a part of my system called Patient Record Management system and in it there is an Appointment Management, and in Appointment you make a timeslot unavailable to others once occupied so here lies the problem:
there are 3 columns that are in my database: date(Date), TimeIn(Time), TimeOut(Time)
this is what i've done so far:

```
    sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM appointment where date = '" & datePicker.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") & "' and TimeIn <= CAST('" & timeinPicker.value.ToString("HH:mm") & "' AS Time) and TimeOut >= CAST('" & timeoutPicker.value.ToString("HH:mm") & "' AS Time)"
```

example if i put 12:00 to timeinPicker and 13:00 to timeoutPicker, all time between 12:00 and 13:00 should be selected, but my problem is it won't get selected, it can only select it if i input exactly 12:00 and 13:00 but when i put 12:01 and 12:59, the sql cant select it like it didnt exist
is there some way to select them so i can know which time is occupied.

P.S. i'm using MySql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076559/mysql-query-between-two-dates-and-two-times

Comment: i got some idea from that question, im gonna try making it like this:

    sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM appointment where date = '" & datePicker.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") & "' and (TimeIn <= CAST('" & timeinPicker.value.ToString("HH:mm") & "' AS Time) and TimeOut >= CAST('" & timeoutPicker.value.ToString("HH:mm") & "' AS Time))"

Answer (score 0):

if you are using java means replace & character with + and try

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM appointment where date = '" + datePicker.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "' and TimeIn <= CAST('" + timeinPicker.value.ToString("HH:mm") + "' AS Timein) and TimeOut >= CAST('" + timeoutPicker.value.ToString("HH:mm") + "' AS Timeout)";
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you should use the parameterized queries always that give you protection from the `Sql Injection`.
You can change your query like this,

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM appointment where date = @DateValue and TimeIn <= CAST(@TimeInValue AS Time) and TimeOut >= CAST(@TimeOutValue AS Time)"
```

And then set the Paramters values to following values using the `AddParamter()` I don't know which programming language you are using so there will be similar method to add the parameter use that,

```
 @DateValue = datePicker.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
 @TimeOutValue = timeoutPicker.value.ToString("HH:mm") 
 @TimeInValue = timeInPicker.value.ToString("HH:mm")
```