# how to find out the from and to from the database duration is between the particular time?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

For example:-

i have the from time as 10:00:00 and to time is 15:00:00 and how can i find out this time is between the range of 12:00:00 and 13:00:00 the time format is checked in the mysql and I have used the **Between** operator too check this record is between the range but I can't get the correct answer.

i want to know whether we can do it in the mysql or php

Comment: show us query u tried

Comment: already answered on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076559/mysql-query-between-two-dates-and-two-times